# How do I uninstall Git from my computer?

Tags: git, shell, github

I am learning Ruby on Rails and am unable to resolve merge conflicts in my Git repository. I was using Github for Windows, which wasn't much help. Trying to repair the damage I've probably created even bigger problems, and cannot deploy to Heroku now. I'd like to uninstall Git completely from my computer, reinstall it, and save all my current work in a new megacommit.

But I haven't found a guide to uninstalling Git anywhere. Could anyone help please? Thanks!

Comment: What does uninstalling Git have to do with removing the .git folder in your workspace folder?

Comment: You don't need to uninstall git. You are having a problem with the repository that you are working on and changes you have made with git in that folder. Uninstalling git won't undo those changes.

Comment: There are instructions here for uninstalling Github for Windows
https://help.github.com/articles/uninstalling-github-for-windows, but it doesn't sound like that is what you really need to do.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of uninstalling Git, you may consider removing the current `.git` directory located at the root of your project (or moving it to a backup place -just in case-).

At the root of your project, run the following commands :

- `git init` to create a fresh `.git` directory, i.e. a Git repository with no commits
- `heroku create` to add the heroku remote.
- `git add .; git commit -m "Initial commit of project XXX"` to create a new initial commit in your repository
- `git push -f heroku master` to push the new repository master.

For more informations, have a look to [Heroku Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)